# Automatically generate flowcharts out of C++ code

Tags: python, c++, flowchart, activity-diagram

I need to **automatically** construct flowcharts out of C++ code, ideally one flowchart per source file.
Is there any tool (preferably C++/Python and either **open-sourced** or **highly configurable** - so I may change the look) that I can use to create flowcharts?

[image: http://www.faqs.org/patents/img/20110088010_08.png]

Comment: I am aware of Enterprise Architect http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/execution_analyzer/generating_sequence_diagram.html can generate sequence diagrams in the background while you debug your code. Once you are finished debugging, it asks you save the generated diagram. All functions where you have set the break-points and those are actually hit during debugging session are covered in the generated sequence diagram.

Comment: So EA gives a *dynamic* analysis, not a static analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`clang/llvm` can generate [graphviz dot files](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Example:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm -o hello.ll hello.cpp
opt hello.ll -dot-cfg -o hello.dot
```

This will output several `.dot` files, one for each function defined in `hello.cpp`.
You can also generate dominance graph, post dominance graph and more (see [here](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#dot-cfg-print-cfg-of-function-to-dot-file)).

After you have your `.dot`files you can use `dot` to convert it to a `.png` file. 
The `.dot` file itself contains only the structure of the graph, so the output of `dot` should be highly configurable (but I am not really familiar with it).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! .dot files are indeed great for the task I have.

Answer (score 2):

Use Enterprise Architect tool.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/execution_analyzer/generating_sequence_diagram.html

You can generate sequence diagram while you debug the code.

Demonstration: [Online Demo](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/debuggingcs/debuggingcs.htm)

Note:- This works with C++ code as well. Just use Native debugger.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is it configurable, can I change the appearance of charts there? The resulting chart in demo you mentioned is kind of stange...

Comment: No, those are sequence diagrams. Sequence diagrams or Activity diagrams are good for object oriented code base, and your question is on C++. If you want flowcharts specifically, then use Code rocket designer. http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com/

Comment: @user1 "This domain is for sale: $12,495"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind plaintext output, 'cflow' will do the job. It's in the repositories of at least Debian, and probably most Linux distro's.

Comment: It seems that cflow creates call graphs but I need flowcharts (how algorithm works)

Comment: Ah right. Yeah it's analyzing your source statically, so if you want to know how your program actually flows at runtime, it won't help you.