# How to create flowchart with python? Optional: Need to support most Code Languages

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write course work and now I stops in a progrees of writing, I want to build application based on Python which can drow Flowcharts of any code(maybe not all but main languages is: **Python, Pascal, c++**). 
On Python I know about **Graphviz+Pyreverse**, but this solution is only for Python code vizualization.

Comment: Good luck then.

Comment: This is a very general question where you might find an answer on google. If you have a more specific question or error feel free to ask it but not a general question like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a python solution.

For C++ use [clang/llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310166/automatically-generate-flowcharts-out-of-c-code#answer-27312183).

For pascal, first use a pascal → C translator, then hand it to clang.